# How to Create Multiple Dispatcher Servlets using Spring MVC java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I'm using Spring MVC 4.1 with Servlet 3.1 and I want to create two servlets using java config, one for normal web application, and another on for Rest APIs, below is my code for web Application initializer (equivalent for web.xml):

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/web"};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {RootApplicationConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    DelegatingFilterProxy securityFilterChain = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter,multipartFilter, securityFilterChain};
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
    registration.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "default");
}
```

The above will only be able to register a default dispatcher servlet, I need to register the rest api but didn't find good suggestions.

What is the best way to do that, and are there other solutions? (thought of adding another class in `getServletConfigClasses()` like RestMvcConfig, but how to map `/api` to that one?)

Comment: Override the `onStartup` method, register your own `DispatcherServlet` here and then call super (or first call super then register yours.

Comment: *Why* do you want multiple servlets? It's nearly always better to just use a single dispatcher and apply appropriate mappings.

Comment: because we have different access points with different security settings, plus we don't want to add /api in each mapping